# Laravel. Не работает Doctrine DBall, в чем дело?

Tags: php, laravel, composer, фреймворк, artisan

Пытаюсь изменить значения в таблице через консоль. Выпадает ошибка

````
Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

at C:\progi\OpenServer\domains\laravel.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection.php:64
60| * return \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver
61| */
62| protected function getDoctrineDriver()
63| {
> 64| return new DoctrineDriver;
65| }
66| }
67|

1 C:\progi\OpenServer\domains\laravel.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:894
Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::getDoctrineDriver()

2 C:\progi\OpenServer\domains\laravel.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\ChangeColumn.php:36
Illuminate\Database\Connection::getDoctrineSchemaManager() ```

Выполняю команду composer require doctrine/dbal
В консоле появляется сообщение, что обновлять нечего. Типа все есть. Но изменения в таблицу все равно внести не могу. После команды php artisan migrate снова консоль пишет

``` Error

Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
````

подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело?

Answer (score 0):

Может уже и поздно, но всё же может кому пригодиться. Попробуйте в папке с проектом в консоли выполнить:
`composer dumpautoload`